# R: Improvement of loop to create distance matrix from data frame

Tags: r, loops, matrix, distance

I am creating a distance matrix using the data from a data frame in R.

My data frame has the temperature of 2244 locations:

```
plot    temperature
A       12
B       12.5
C       15
...     ...
```

I would like to create a matrix that shows the temperature difference between each pair of locations:

```
.   A    B    C
A   0    0.5  3
B   0.5  0    0.5
C   3    2.5  0
```

This is what I have come up with in R:

```
temp_data  #my data frame with the two columns: location and temperature

temp_dist<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=length(temp_data[,1]), ncol=length(temp_data[,1]))
temp_dist<-as.data.frame(temp_dist)
names(temp_dist)<-as.factor(temp_data[,1]) #the locations are numbers in my data
rownames(temp_dist)<-as.factor(temp_data[,1])

for (i in 1:2244)
{
  for (j in 1:2244)
  {
   temp_dist[i,j]<-abs(temp_data[i,2]-temp_data[j,2])
  }
}
```

I have tried the code with a small sample with:

```
 for (i in 1:10)
```

and it works fine. 
My problem is that the computer has been running now for two full days and it hasn't finished.

I was wondering if there is a way of doing this quicker. I am aware that loops in loops take lots of times and I am trying to fill in a matrix of more than 5 million cells and it makes sense it takes so long, but I am hoping there is a formula that gets the same result in a quicker time as I have to do the same with the precipitation and other variables.

I have also read about `dist`, but I am unsure if with the data frame I have I can use that formula.

I would very much appreciate your collaboration.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `dist(temp_data$temperature, method="euclidean", diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE)` on some sample data? I  have no idea how long it will take on a big dataset, but it may be worth looking into.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446825/perform-pairwise-comparison-of-matrix?

Comment: It was instant... Sorry for such a silly question and many thanks for the answer. @romansegelskyi it was a similar question indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps just looking for the following?

```
out <- dist(temp_data$temperature, upper=TRUE, diag=TRUE)
out
#     1   2   3
# 1 0.0 0.5 3.0
# 2 0.5 0.0 2.5
# 3 3.0 2.5 0.0
```

If you want different row/column names, it seems you have to convert this to a matrix first:

```
out_mat <- as.matrix(out)
dimnames(out_mat) <- list(temp_data$plot, temp_data$plot)
out_mat
#     A   B   C
# A 0.0 0.5 3.0
# B 0.5 0.0 2.5
# C 3.0 2.5 0.0
```

Comment: This answer was indeed really helpful but I have found a problem. The dist objet that `dist()` creates does not have labels, therefore I can't use it for a mantel test.

Comment: I have tried to use `labels(dist(temp_data$temperature, upper=TRUE, diag=TRUE))<-temp_data[,1]` Sadly that does not work. I have also tried with `vegdist()`. When I use species distance I get the labels:`Class 'dist'  atomic [1:2516646] 0.5 0.963 0.412 0.929 0.788 ...
  ..- attr(*, "Size")= int 2244
  ..- attr(*, "Labels")= chr [1:2244] "33013" "35443" "52809" "38917" ...
  ..- attr(*, "Diag")= logi TRUE
  ..- attr(*, "Upper")= logi FALSE
  ..- attr(*, "method")= chr "jaccard"
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language vegdist(x = species_mat[, 2:248], method = "jaccard", diag = T)`

Comment: @Greta, I'm guessing you're trying to add the `dimnames`. See my update.

Comment: I think I have found another solution. Once I have the dist object I have added a new attribute `attr(out, "Labels")<-as.factor(temp_data[1:2244,1])` The Mantel test has managed to do it. I don't know if your solution would work as `mantel()` needs a dist object. Is that ok if I add my bit of code to your answer? That would be the complete answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Or just as an alternative from the toolbox:

```
m <- with(temp_data, abs(outer(temperature, temperature, "-")))
dimnames(m) <- list(temp_data$plot, temp_data$plot)
m
#     a   b   c
# a 0.0 0.5 3.0
# b 0.5 0.0 2.5
# c 3.0 2.5 0.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I will keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: This does seem to be faster. +1

Comment: Actually, I guess not faster, but still a nice alternative.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Thanks! It seems to be 3-4 times slower than your `dist`, using 2244 temperatures. Well, it just came to my mind and I could just as well share it.